# where can I enter api-key of wakatime in eclipse?

Tags: api-key, wakatime

I am trying to use wakatime in eclipse to trace my code work,but I can't find the place to enter the api key.If you know about it, please help me out.Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

To put API-key in Eclipse, let come into File > Waka Time > API Key then paste API-key.

To view your api key: https://wakatime.com/settings/api-key

FAQ entry about changing your api key: https://wakatime.com/faq#change-api-key